# Different timing between mysqlslap and mysqli_query

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I'm running the exact same query by 2 different ways (on localhost on both)

First using mysqlslap

```
mysqlslap --iterations=100 --query="INSERT INTO table (id, name, distance, latlng, is_waypoint, path_id) VALUES (452, '', 0, 'blablablablablalblalbla', 0, 0);" --create-schema=myschema  --user=myuser
```

**Total time for 100 execution : 0.035 second.**

Second using a php script :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (`id`, `name`, `distance`, `latlng`, `is_waypoint`, `path_id`) VALUES (452, '', 0, 'blablablablablalblalbla', 0, 0)";
$res = $g_Database->query($sql);
```

**Total time for 100 execution : 3.215 second.**

How could the result be so different ?

It can't be mysql optimisation as the first result show the queries are fast.
Maybe the php connection ?

```
   <?php


$db_hostname = "localhost";
$db_username = "xxx";
$db_password = "xxx";
$db_database = "xxx";


$iterations = 100;
$timings = array();

$sql = "INSERT INTO table (`id`, `name`, `distance`, `latlng`, `is_waypoint`, `path_id`) VALUES (442, '', 0, '{lat:43.".rand(0,1000) .",lng:1.".rand(0,100) ."}', 0, 0)";

$mysqli = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);

for ($i = 0; $i < $iterations; $i++) 
{
    $timer = microtime(true);
    $mysqli->query($sql);
    $timings[] = microtime(true) - $timer;
}

echo "<pre>" . PHP_EOL;
echo "Serveur HTTP : " . (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : "") . PHP_EOL;
echo "Val Min : " . min($timings) . PHP_EOL;
echo "Val Max : " . max($timings) . PHP_EOL;
echo "Val Total : " . array_sum($timings) . PHP_EOL;
echo "Val Avg : " . array_sum($timings) / count($timings) . PHP_EOL;
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The comma in your question is a decimal, or a thousand separator? How is the 100 loop done in PHP? Also how is the PHP connection made?

Comment: One inserts the same ID repeatedly and probably ignores the subsequent requests with an error. The second inserts up to 100 entries, but due to collisions on the random function may insert significantly less. Strip out the ID in both to get a better example.

Comment: decimal => i edited the post, also i add the construct, query and time function i use

Comment: forget about the rand() func i tried with or without this doesn't change anything.

Comment: also the id is not a unique field in my table => i edited the post to remove the rand()

Comment: Where is the loop done? `$escaped_sql` is also not safe.

Comment: i add the loop at the end

Comment: to avoid the questions about the php query and connection process i rewrite it to make it more simple => Post edited

Comment: no one can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are *some* of the reasons for differences, plus flaws in the benchmarking.

If `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY`, you are getting an error -- Duplicate Key 442 -- every time.  This slows things down.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

mysqlslap opens up multiple connections -- how many?  How many inserts per transaction?  Let's see the slap output.  Your PHP will have only one connection.

The PHP code is probably committing each INSERT one at a time.  3.215s for 100 inserts is unreasonably slow; I would expect more like 1s on a HDD (faster on SSD).

The min and max might be informative; let's see your output.

Insert thousands of rows per second is possible, but takes fancier code than your benchmark.

Secondary indexes *may* be slowing things down.  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.